# How can I determine whether dimensions are related?

Tags: mdx, ssas, ssas-2008

I am developing a query builder application that generates MDX and trying to get customer counts from a cube using the following, which works just fine:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.X AS (
    { [Customer].[Gender].[Female]}, 
    [Customer].[Customer].Children
).Count
SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM [Adventure Works]
```

However, if the user drags in a dimension that is not related to the customer like:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.X AS (
    { [Customer].[Gender].[Female]}, 
    { [Employee].[Status].[Active], [Employee].[Status].[Inactive]},  
    [Customer].[Customer].Children
).Count
SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM [Adventure Works]
```

the count result obviously becomes incorrect.

Is there a way to determine whether a dimension is related to the customer so that I can exclude it from the generated MDX query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using the [Exists( Set_Expression1 , Set_Expression2 [, MeasureGroupName] )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144936.aspx) function. No need to manually determine which dimensions are related. The [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144936.aspx) function filters out the unrelated tuples, leaving only the 
`{ [Customer].[Customer].Children, [Customer].[Gender].[Female]}` set to do the count over.

Here is the MDX:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.X AS Exists(
    [Customer].[Customer].Children,
    {[Customer].[Gender].[Female]}
    *
    {[Employee].[Status].[Active], [Employee].[Status].[Inactive]}
).Count
SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1):

This information can be retrieved from the cube through [AMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124924.aspx). The [`Cube`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.cube.aspx) class contains all the cube metadata you'll need.